# Retrieve source from MathJax 3.0 processed formula

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

How to retrieve source equation from a MathJax 3.0 processed equation?

I already try to

- parse the processed equation to see if the source were inside.
- search in the documentation for a JS function, but the API are "under construction"

I made a JSFiddle to help solving the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/g3j82cdv/

**HTML**

```
<span id="equation">\[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]</span>

<h3>Expected</h3>
x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.

<h3>Text</h3>
<div id="source-text"></div>

<h3>Html</h3>
<div id="source-html"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var src = document.getElementById('equation');
document.getElementById("source-text").innerText = src.innerText;
document.getElementById("source-html").innerText = src.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just remove the delimiters from equation innerText

```js
var src = document.getElementById('equation');
document.getElementById("source-text").innerText = src.innerText.substring(2, src.innerText.length - 2);;
```

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

  <span id="equation">\[x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.\]</span>
  <h3>Expected</h3>
  x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.
  
  <h3>Text</h3>
  <div id="source-text"></div>
    
    
    
    <br>
```

Comment: It's not working. In your snippet, the equation is not yet processed by MathJax. Try in my JSFiddle, it's not that simple.